# Merging of cells in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I need a **datagrid** control like below.
I want to implement cell merge like functionality in a **datagrid** in **silverlight**. I have some rows which display a single value and some rows return all the values for all columns.So How to implement something like **colspan** for a particular row in **datagrid** ?

Like this

[image]

Please see the link
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightcontrols/thread/79a7b371-738a-43e5-a3e3-7a26c946aa46